# Buildfire Firebase integration login error: "Invalid Integration Token"

Tags: buildfire

I have an app using the Firebase integration as described here: https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/firebase-integration/

When I use the integration token to create a custom token and then login to Firebase, I get an error saying `Invalid Integration Token`. I have verified that my database name is correct. I have tried both Firestore and Realtime Database integrations and have the same issue.

When I create the same integration token with Development Mode checked, it works in my web-based apps (e.g. hosted on app.buildfire.com) but I get the same error when trying to login from my app on my phone.

Any tips on how to fix this? I have an old integration token that I made months ago that works ok, but I am using a different Firebase account for our production environment and need a new integration token.

Comment: After further investigation, it looks like my old integration token that I thought worked, no longer works on my mobile app (still works on the web app). This token used to work though, we have been testing with it for over a month.

Comment: I have made sure to register my plugin for this token under "Manage" on the Buildfire Integrations page, and it still does not work on my mobile app (and it still works ok in the web app).